# finding a number in a range swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a number that I get from JSON, this number represents an age. Users give me a range of two ages and may code is supposed to check if this number I'm getting from JSON is in the range.

here is my code and it gives me error

> Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context?

```
 let age = "40"

 if  Int(AgeFrom) ... Int(AgeTO) ~= Int(age) {

   print("yes")

}
```

**Update**

if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
      var ages = String

```
  let json = JSON(value)
  for (key, subJson) in json {

      ages.append(subJson["age"].string!)
 }
        guard let min = Int(self.DropDownFrom.selectedItem!) else { return }
        guard let max = Int(self.DropDownTo.selectedItem!) else { return }
     for fitage in ages {
        switch ages
           {
           case (min...max):
                print ("Age is in range")
                default:
         print ("Nope, not this time")
     }
    }
```

Still gives me an error.

Comment: `if Int(AgeFrom) <=  age && age <= Int(AgeTO){}`?

Comment: `Int.init(String)` is a failable initializer, so the type of `Int(age)` is `Int?`, not `Int`. You need to unwrap it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the optionals because the `Int(:String)` method might not have a valid answer.

Best way to do this is kind of thing is with `guard`

```
guard let min = Int(AgeFrom) else { return }
guard let max = Int(AgeTo)   else { return }
```

And from there you can go with the simple `if` statement:

```
if (min <= age && age <= max)
{
    print ("Age is in range")
}
```

or get really fancy and use the `switch` statement pattern matching syntax (which I much prefer)

```
switch age
{
    case (min...max):
        print ("Age is in range")
    default:
        print ("Nope, not this time")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did the same but it gives me an error. Because I think I'm looping through an array of Stings, not just one number. Can you look it my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

### if - simplicity and readability

It is a basic thing in programming, checking if an optional is between two other optional values with an `if`:

```
if Int(AgeFrom)! <= Int(age)! && Int(AgeTO)! >= Int(age)! {
    print("It is in the range!")
}
```

### switch - multiple cases handling

However, I recommend using a `switch` for case handling:

```
switch(Int(AgeFrom)! <= Int(age)!, Int(AgeTO)! >= Int(age)!){
    case (true,true): print("Yes, it fits the range")
    case (false,true): print("Too young!")
    case (true,false): print("Too old!")
}
```

---

The second solution is far better for multiple cases of the age value, especially when it's outside the range.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried your answer and other answers but it gives me the same error because I'm looping through an array and it's not only one number

Answer (score 1):

You can also use optional binding:

```
if let ageFrom = Int(ageFrom),
    let ageTo = Int(ageTo),
    ageFrom...ageTo ~= age
{
    print("yes")
} else {
    print("no")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to unwrap the optionals:

```
    if  Int(AgeFrom)!...Int(AgeTO)! ~= Int(age)! {
        print("yes")
    }
```

of course that is the unsafe way of unwrapping, since it will crash if the conversion of `AgeFrom`, `AgeTO` or `age` fail.